# How do videogames store information offscreen?

Tags: game-design, architecture, software-engineering, game-mechanics

I'm trying to make a videogame from scratch, but I'm really new to this and keep running into basic issues. Most importantly, how do videogames store offscreen information? What I mean is, how does the program know what to display next onto the screen? Or even, if the player changes the environment, how does this change remain for the next time it loads onto the screen?

For example, in New Super Mario Bros, if you hit a ? block and then go off screen, and come back, it still remains hit. How is this information kept and then executed the next time the player loads the block? Why doesn't it just reset?

Comment: Pedantry:  In Super Mario Bros, if you hit a ? block and then go off screen, you can't come back -- the game only scrolls in one direction, and all warp pipes are single-direction.

Comment: When you read a text document and you scroll down, does your word processor delete the beginning of the document?

Comment: The monitor shows a window into the gameworld. The world exist outside your window- you just don't see it.

Comment: The much more typical newbie programming question is: "How do I display my information on screen?". Work through any programming tutorial and when you arrive at that question you should already have the answer to your question.

Comment: @Philipp : Love the comment

Comment: Here's an HTML5 game tutorial that uses pixijs. Takes about an hour and a half to get to the section talking about viewports. I think it'll help you wrap your mind around the concept of separation of logical state and what the user sees: http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=5226

Comment: I wonder what kind of development environment you're working with that keeping things *off* the screen sounds more complicated than getting them *on* the screen :) Or is this just a purely theoretical question?

Comment: You can actually see some unloading behavior in some older games of the NES era (mostly enemy positions; Mega Man). This is the reason a lot of older games force one-way movement (Original SMB, Adventure island). Some of these were game design decisions, of course.

Comment: I don't think this question is as unreasonable as people are making it out to be. Some toy games I wrote in BASIC way back kept their state in the screen contents, and I suspect even some commercial console games kept state in tile map contents. Yes it's contrary to best practices and unreasonable given modern resource scales, but for someone who hasn't been *taught* these practices it's very intuitive for state and presentation to overlap.

Comment: Now, how does reality store information outside your field of view? :v

Comment: @TrevorPowell They mentioned *New* Super Mario Bros., the platformer for Nintendo DS and onwards. That game does allow you to go backwards.

Comment: I will admit that the example given is rather trivial but for continuous open-world games like Minecraft, the answer to this question can get quite elaborate and complex. Chunking is definitely not a trivial task, especially when the game clients are connected to a central server.

Comment: it's called variables

Comment: @Compynerd255 At the time of my comment, the question cited Super Mario Bros.  The OP edited in the word "New" later, as a simple glance at the question's history would have shown.

Comment: @TrevorPowell Oh, OK, that makes sense. I actually didn't know that question history was browsable - most askers mark their edits with EDIT: or similar. Sorry about that.

Comment: @TrevorPowell Even in the classic SMB you could still go back a distance, depending on how far you'd progressed through the level, so you'd indeed be able to go back and find the ? block already used. The game certainly did **not** scroll in only one direction. Your remark about the warp pipes is correct, though.

Comment: @TomLint Hi, welcome to the site!   I'm honored that you'd choose to join just to tell me about how wrong I am.  :)  You are mistaken, though.  I am looking at the classic NES SMB right now;  the screen does not ever scroll to the left, no matter how much you try to move left.  Take a look for yourself;  your memories are probably playing tricks on you, or you're thinking of something other than the original NES SMB.  Your remark about the correctness of my remark about the warp pipes is correct, though.

Comment: @TrevorPowell Ah. I see. I guess I was confused about which SMB you were referring to, as I assumed it wasn't called Super Mario Bros. until the advent of the SNES.

Answer (score 58):

Usually you should separate the logical state of your game environment from the visual representation.

The player might only see a small part of it on their screen, but you still keep the state of the whole level in memory and usually also calculate the game mechanics for the whole level. When your world is so huge that this would require too much ram and/or cpu, you can suspend further away areas to hard drive.

Your rendering subroutine checks which parts of the level are currently on the screen and then only draws those. Whatever is off-screen isn't drawn, but that doesn't mean it isn't updated.

Answer (score 37):

You are going at it backwards.

You start with the logical state of your game and model that. The whole logical state of the entire world will almost certainly be too much to be held in memory at once, so you break it down in smaller parts that can be loaded and saved independently. These parts are often referred to as *chunks*. These chunks can form a continuous world, but they can also be separate levels/instances. Terminology varies wildly depending on genre and which technique you want to use.

Then you load those parts that are of interest -- that is, chunks that are in the vicinity of the player. Chunks that are too far away are saved to disk/permanent storage and unloaded from memory.

And then, as last step, you determine what is actually visible and create the *visual representation* of the current game state and render it on the screen.

Of course you would try not to rebuild the entire visual representation every time but cache it and re-use it if you have parts that are already constructed, but that is the main principle.

---

This holds true for any program that has output. If you write a program with a normal GUI, like a text editor, you would likely model the document, and then the GUI would determine the state and visible parts of the document and render it to screen. Or fill form fields appropriately, or else.

The main gist is: Think about where and how you store the data first (probably alongside with how to represent it). Almost every program has to deal with data storage. There is only very few cases in which you don't store any data.

Comment: You might need to store relationships between chunks too, like you push a button in some level and the door is open in other one (crappy example).

Comment: @coredump yeah, sure, but thats pretty basic stuff.I only said they need to be able to be loaded and saved independently, that doesn#t mean that the data needs to be truly independent. And you can have both chunks for spatial data, and other data structures for a purely logical model. The possibilities are pretty much endless.

Comment: chunks? I'd call those smaller pieces _levels_.

Comment: This is good, except for "so you break it down in smaller parts that can be loaded and saved independently. These parts are often referred to as chunks", which seems to be specific to games with very large worlds. Many games don't need to do such a thing. I wouldn't be surprised if you could fit in memory all the level data for every 2D sidescroller ever created.

Comment: Depends on what game you are having. Even levels can be subdivided in chunks if the level gets big enough. But that isn't that important. The important thing is that *completely agnostic to the game* you need to have a logical model and a seperate view of your logical model. The exact  characteristics of your data structure depend on the requirements. A racing game will probably load each track as seperate "level", while an open.world game like Fallout probably loads chunks of the world.

Comment: @immibis See my second paragraph about text processing. Thats a good example for the same principle, but not used for a game, but for a normal business application. Obviuosly, you wouldn't call a document a "chunk" or a "level". The main principle is: if your data gets to big, you need to split it and load it according to what you need, whatever that may be or however it might be split (it wouldn#t be wise to store all tracks of a racing game in memory when you only need one at the same time).

Comment: @gbjbaanb 'Level' is a dated term and 'chunk' is much more comprehensive and a clearly distinguished concept. Not all chunks are levels and not all levels are chunks.

Comment: I think a helpful way to think about it is that it should be technically possible to play the entire game without a single pixel being rendered, that is, the entirety of the game is separate from the visual representation.

Comment: @Lilienthal sure, but I think level is still in common usage, and many games still have the concept - I'm not sure any of them pop a "loading chunk" screen when fetching a new "arena" then the player traverses them. Hence it might be more understandable, particularly to the OP who is new to games than a relatively technical term he may never have seen before.

Comment: "Area" would also be a more user-friendly term. Or just say the name of the area - "Loading town centre", "Loading docks", etc... Of course, a lot of games now have invisible background loading.

Comment: (Be careful with invisible background loading; as I recall *The Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess* had a design flaw where you could stall the loading thread indefinitely, and then walk around areas that hadn't been loaded yet, and walk through where there should've been walls, and so on)

Comment: @gbjbaanb Fair, but this answer defines the term right before (correctly) identifying the concept as a 'chunk'. The problem with using another term like level is that games are so diverse that calling it that becomes confusing. 'Chunk' doesn't have that problem as it abstracts the size/complexity/scope of the underlying element that's loaded and unloaded. It *could* be level, it could be an area, it could be a single house. It could be a combination of all those things.

Comment: @gbjbaanb 'Chunk' is completely agnosic to the thing that is divided. It simply refers to a *chunk* of data or a *chunk* of memory. *Level* on the other hand as strong connotations gaming. *Area* is misleading as well, because it means that you divide/split by spatial position. A chunk doesn't need to be split by location, it can also be split in any other way.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, you keep a map (e.g. in an array) and draw the visible part of it to the screen, and don't read back from the screen.

But in some older systems you would literally keep data offscreen. There would be, say, 400x300 pixels of video memory for a 320x200 display, and you would define a viewport into that ("start at X=10 Y=30"). So you could scroll the screen by just adjusting a register. You wouldn't have to spend the hundred thousand cycles required to move the bytes around, you just change where the video hardware starts reading them.

The NES has this, combined with a tile-based system: http://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/PPU_scrolling

The NES never constructs the full image in memory, because it doesn't have enough RAM. Instead, there's a RAM array that defines a two-screen-wide set of tiles. One byte per kind of tile. The video hardware looks up the tile and X/Y offset coordinates in order to decide what pixel should appear at any point.

Comment: While true, thats an implementation detail - the main principle is still that you have some logical state and render it (and ofc as I said cache some parts of it, already prepare some things that will come into the viewpoint next etc.).

Comment: @Polygnome Well, I've written a lot of games where the screen *was* the game state. It's amazing what you can do with 4 000 bytes of VRAM! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are asking this kind of question you are going to have a long road to get to the point where you can make a game. But, getting to the heart of your question, the program can save the state of many different things in variables which are in the back end of your program. Let's look at a couple of examples.

Mario Brothers (or similar) saves the state of the level you are in. that might include how far you have gone before you died, if a block was hit or not. In some a more object oriented sense, the game just says "be a block here" and the block exists. then when you hit the block, the block changes its own internal state to say "I was hit". Data like that can be stored in a variety of ways.

Your word processor saves its data in a data structure. Now there are lots of these and many ways they can be implemented, but probably it uses some form of a tree. In a tree you have at least one node. Anything added before it goes to the left. Anything added after it, goes to the right. After you add three nodes you have two of them hanging off the middle node. And the tree can grow even larger with new pieces being added anywhere and the tree will rebuild itself.
[image: Example of tree]
Or think about shooter games where your enemy wanders around. Each of them has variables which tracks their location, life, etc. so that when you wound one, it will remember that it was hurt.

All of these things require a knowledge of data structures. It goes way beyond what you see on the screen. I would suggest reading about arrays, lists, hashes (sometimes called dictionaries or maps) and then coming back to your problem.

Here are some good starting materials:

- http://visualgo.net/

Answer (score 0):

To an extent, this is a function of how 3D is rendered. For example, OpenGL will automatically cull geometry outside of the -1.0, +1.0 range in X-Y screen space (Z is more complex but similar). Culled geometry never generates fragments (approximately pixels) and thus is never turned into actual imagery, despite being sent to the system to render. In any case, it's impossible to write to space outside the render window (if everything is working as it should).

In some contexts, it's enough to rely on this behavior as an optimization. However, you still have to pass all your game data through at least one rendering stage (vertex shaders) before the video card can know what is visible. In something like, say, Skyrim, that would be impractical. Not only do you have to send every vertex in the world through the rendering pipeline, but you have to *load* every vertex into system/video memory. That's inefficient, if even possible.

So, many games will make use of CPU-based culling. They will typically implement some sort of LOD (level of detail) system, where the quality and existence of assets are impacted by how important they are assessed to be in a given context. A pyramidal mesh might be an acceptable approximation for a mountain if you're 50 miles away from it. If you can't see it at all (like it's blocked by other mountains), there's no need to even load it. There are a number of more complex methods for doing this that are topics I don't feel are directly relevant to the depth requested by this question, but look at [tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation_(computer_graphics)) for one of the most common examples.

The real gist of this is that the visuals are only the product of the game. The actual data has nothing directly to do with what you are seeing or not seeing most of the time, and the data is filtered by various stages to remove extraneous information before hitting the point where a picture is written to the screen. Depending on the engine design, visuals can be extremely decoupled from the actual game logic, so far as something like having a 2D and 3D interface to the same game is a possibility. It's even possible for many game engines to run with no output what-so-ever; sometimes this is used to test game AI.

That's where things can get complicated, though. In something simple like a Mario game, it is not too prohibitive to calculate the movement of all enemies in the level, even if they are not visible. In modern contexts, what is *happening* off-screen is an actual question of serious consideration. If there are multiple entire cities of NPCs, how do you handle how they behave when they are completely culled - like when the player is in a different city? Do you really want to be computing hundreds of NPCs' decisions all the way across the map? The answer is usually no, but the exact approach to accomplish not doing so can vary, and it can have some impacts upon the game.

It's important to note that this is how things work *now*. The old Mario games themselves were likely programmed in very different ways (I can't speak to the exact ways), given the extreme hardware limitations at the time. The concept of 3D did not exist back then; yet today almost all games, even ones which are entirely 2D, use 3D rendering in some form, even if they don't know they do. Modern video hardware is 3D first, and 2D rendering (at least when it makes use of the hardware properly) merely ignores the 3rd dimension.

Comment: In addition to LoD techniques, it'd be good to add a scenegraph to this answer - where a world can be held in memory and 'CPU culled' based on what is within the view.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: video games keep the state of the game world in some abstract data structure that has nothing to do with the screen. This is then rendered to the screen as needed (i.e., depending on where the player is).

Games that use the video RAM directly for state purposes were around in the '80s in the 8-bit, maybe even in the 16-bit era, but unless you are developing for that platform or for some µC which counds its RAM in KB instead of GB, forget about it.

That said, you seem to be very new to everything related to programming, or the question would not have come up. I suggest going at it step by step, programming very easy things first; maybe something that has only textual input/output (simple prompts and all that). To be honest, the time when I did that is around 30 years past, so I have no really good resources for you, but your local library *might* just be better than the internet to give you a really good start in programming.